# KALI suddenly fails: Failed to start login service, booting impossible

Tags: boot, kali-linux, login

The situation is as follows:

1. I ran dist-upgrade
2. I start my kali
3. I choose the proper OS-entry in the grub-selection-list
4. I enter my LUKS-encryption key
5. The system boots
6. The system-boot-process stops with a message like: Failed to start login service
7. Doing all the steps starting from point 2 BUT choosing "emergency/recovery mode"
8. I can login then...
9. Checking all the logs, but  the mentioned error seems to be missing in the logs
10. How can I find out the reason for this error in order to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, but I knew for a fact that this was due to the aborted upgrade and/or dist-upgrade processes.

Here is what I did to fix it:

1. Enter recovery mode
2. Start networking:

   ```sh
   ifconfig eth0 up && dhclient eth0
   ```
3. Complete the install:

   ```sh
   dpkg --configure -a
   ```

   This returned some broken packages, including `network-manager` and `network-manager-gnome`.
4. As `apt` tells you, run:

   ```sh
   apt-get --fix-broken install
   ```
5. Start the `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade` process again:

   ```sh
   apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y
   ```
6. Reboot; it now works normally.